# SQLAlchemy db.text().bindparams() without clobbering

Tags: sqlalchemy

I just discovered that if you use the same name in bindparams twice in the same query, the second value clobbers the first one.  For a contrived example:

```
db.session.query(MyTable).filter(
    db.or_(
        db.text("my_table.field = :value").bindparams(value=value1),
        db.text("my_table.field = :value").bindparams(value=value2),
    )
)
```

Here you would only get things with `value2`.  `value1` would not appear in the query.

Is there a general purpose way to fix this?

Btw, `db.text()` bits in my real query access nested jsonb properties, so please don't answer telling me to just use the column objects in this query in place of `db.text()`.

Comment: just to be clear, is there a reason you cannot use `or_(MyTable.field == value1, MyTable.field == value2)`?

Comment: Read my last sentence.  I'm accessing json fields.  The real ```db.text``` bit looks more like ```(my_table.json_field ->> 'key')::text = :value```

Comment: so... are you *sure* you cannot use `MyTable.field1[('key1', 'key2')].astext == value1`?  SqlAlchemy has full support for the  Postgres JSONB type  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB

Comment: @IfLoop thanks! That really helps. I'm still interested in the answer to this question though.